# Is it legal to get access to protected base class via a friend of additional child class in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, friend, protected

Consider we have some third party library with a class `B` derived from `A` using `protected` inheritance. So having an object of `B` we may not normally access its base `A`.

But we can create some additional class `C` (no objects of which will ever be constructed) deriving it from `B` and declare its friendship with the function that needs access to `A`-portion of `B`-objects. There are even two options how to get the access:

```
// some 3rd party library
struct A {};
struct B : protected A {};

// our code to get access to A
struct C : B { friend int main(); };

int main() {
    const B & b = B{};
    [[maybe_unused]] const A & a1 = static_cast<const C&>( b ); // #1: ok everywhere
    [[maybe_unused]] const A & a2 = b; // #2: ok in GCC and MSVC
}
```

The option #1 with `static_cast<const C&>` works in all compilers. But is it well formed (no undefined behavior)?

The option #2 is even shorter, but it works only in GCC and MSVC, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zj146bKsb

Given that Clang refuses to accept it, is it the only compiler that fulfills properly the standard here?

Comment: *"using protected inheritance"* - I doubt it is used in the wild. I certainly have never seen it employed in all my time doing C++. I think it exists solely "for completeness" or to provide fodder for language lawyer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is it well formed (no undefined behavior)?

Yes undefined behavior.

> **[expr.static.cast]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#2) An lvalue of type “cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to cv2 D”, where D is a class derived from B, if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If B is a virtual base class of D or a base class of a virtual base class of D, or if no valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists ([conv.ptr]), the program is ill-formed. An xvalue of type “cv1 B” can be cast to type “rvalue reference to cv2 D” with the same constraints as for an lvalue of type “cv1 B”. **If the object of type “cv1 B” is actually a base class subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

We do not have an actual `C` there when casting `b`. So we slip right there to the last sentence calling the cast itself undefined.

> Given that Clang refuses to accept it, is it the only compiler that fulfills properly the standard here?

Yes, it is. `B` has no special relationship with `main`, no friendship. So the `A` base is inaccessible in that scope. One may only convert pointers (and references) to derived classes into pointers (and references) to base classes if said bases are accessible:

> **[conv.ptr]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.ptr#3) A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a complete class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base class ([class.derived]) of D. If B is an inaccessible ([class.access]) or ambiguous ([class.member.lookup]) base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. [...]

Comment: Worth noting however, that "protected" is still "public with extra steps".  [class.access.base/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.access.base#4) lays it down, and [here it is in action](https://godbolt.org/z/3jbjYoz4r). It's just as accessible as a public base if one really needs it to be.